# Can't download a certain large file - error: Failed - Network Error

Tags: networking, google-chrome, internet, download, file-download

I have been trying to download something all day with no luck. It came in two parts: One 250kb that downloaded no problem, and one 8GB rar file that I am having issues with. I tried on multiple browsers and it did not work.

Every time, the download starts, goes for a few seconds at very slow speed of 250kbps and gets an error along the lines of: Failed - Network Error (in chrome) or a similar message in every other browser I tried. I am on ethernet and SpeedTest shows 100mbps Download speed. 
The file is one my friend uploaded on a site called AnonFile. It took a while and I do not want him to have to reupload, which I do not think will work anyway.

What I have tried so far:
- Multiple browsers = all same error
- Disabled all antivirus, Chrome antivirus, windows defender = same error
- VPN, proxy = same error
- Laptop using WiFi, not ethernet = same error
- Unplug and replug router power = same error

What can I do? Any help is greatly appreciated. Could it be my ISP blocking this large download? I think that may be it, as I played games, browsed internet, and did several test downloads of things like mp3 files all successfully. Please, provide any input. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sounds like it is more likely to be an ISP or host issue. Most file sharing hosts will have a hard time hosting a file that large. Mailing a USB drive will likely be a far more reliably method for a file that large.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a dedicated file downloader that can segment the download.

Browsers are not good with large files & every browser you've tried so far will have some partial, busted file clogging up its cache now, as well as your ISP's caching. Cached files will simply be fetched again, over & over, even if they are borked:\ Clearing your cache won't clear your ISP's cache, so you're chasing your tail trying that repeatedly.
If you've a slow or inconsistent line, low-quality WiFi, or the host itself is poor, that will not be helping.

Additionally, a lot of these file sharing sites [I don't know AnonFile so can't comment specifically] have a data cap, of either a given size or a given speed. If you hit the cap then either the download will slow to a crawl, or you will be sent some kind of 'time's up, come back tomorrow' type message. If that's not being sent correctly or your browser doesn't recognise it, that could be another reason. If you get the same amout of data with each try, then that could likely be only the part cached already by your ISP on its way to you.

A dedicated downloader ought to correctly interpret that 'come back later' message & just be capable of sitting & waiting until it can gain access again.

You could try something like [Wget](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) which I've never actually tried myself, but was recommended for Windows users on a large file-hosting site I used for a decade or more. It's command-line, so might not be the simplest tool to use. I found a GUI version for Windows [completely untested] at http://winwget.sourceforge.net

Maybe [JDownloader](http://jdownloader.org) would also be a likely candidate for this type of task. This is one I use myself [on Mac, though it's cross-platform] & find very reliable. It's Java-based & comes with its own GUI. It also has nice browser integration to capture download links.
Both freeware - I have no affiliation to either.

If neither of those can hack it, then next bet would be as already mentioned in comments - mail it on a USB/Flash/SD…

<sup>I know we don't like software recommendations on here, but the request wasn't for software but a new method to try. Recommending software that can use that method just goes along with the answer.</sup>

Comment: JDownloaderSetup.exe: on virustotal.com, 15 of 65 security vendors and no sandboxes flagged this file as malicious. Just FYI, I don't know if it means that it is infected

Comment: @HoRn - JDownloader's great. I use it for everything. It will even do YouTube downloads, so you don't need another app for that. Make sure you get it directly from them & not some dodgy "4th party" site.

Comment: Clean. virustotal is simple, green for clean, orange for 'don't know' red for bad - https://www.virustotal.com/gui/url/7a7af432e74c1df580f711356b514d73704fdaa7340a8aba0485ee40ea04fae8 <- that's an analysis of the direct download link from JDownloader.org

Comment: Surely I download it from https://jdownloader.org/download/index, so maybe it's a false positive analysis. But my AVG also detects it as FileRepMalware. I'm not sure if I should install it

Comment: Your call. Can't make the decision for you.

Comment: I download JDownloaderSetup.exe from jdownloader.org and check it with virustotal. Results: https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/ecf4cfa5da9ed6fe27722909d4ef811590e44db4fbb58e07f5471f9dc2673648

Comment: None of them detect it as the same thing. False positive. JD is a 'free-spirit' app, used by many for less than sparklingly clean 'work'. Even downloading directly from YouTube is 'illegal' [or more specifically, against the user agreement]. Major antivirus companies hate you to have any connection to 'piracy' so flag any & all apps like this as 'dodgy'. Sure it's 'dodgy' - it enables you to bypass many online restrictions web service providers would rather you couldn't.

Comment: I'm not advocating 'piracy' as such, but sometimes it's a simple convenience. Personally I use it to 'steal' TV shows I already pay subscriptions for [Apple TV, Amazon, Netflix etc] , to avoid having to use my smart TV's abysmal user interface & lack of sound routing options. Sosume.

Comment: Ok, I see, thank you.